# Command execution elapsed time in jshell

Tags: java, jshell

I looked for an option to have jshell report the execution time of a command, but I could not find any.

Then my question is what is the best way to have elapsed time reported when submitting a command for execution in jshell?

**Example**

To check the time required to perform 100k string concatenations (e.g. to compare to `StringBuffer.append()`)

My basic solution is:

```java
/reset
/set feedback verbose
int i;
long t0;
String s="";
for(t0=System.nanoTime(),i=0; i<100000; ++i){
s+=i;
} long elapsed=System.nanoTime()-t0;
```

Where jshell executes the loop in a whole single step and prints the elapsed time after completing all iterations.

Then to compare to a different solution (using StringBuffer)

```java
/reset
/set feedback verbose
int i;
long t0;
StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder();
for(t0=System.nanoTime(),i=0; i<100000; ++i){
b.append(i);
} long elapsed=System.nanoTime()-t0;
```

Is there a better, cleaner, smarter way?

---

PS: I know the measure you get with this approach is not accurate, though this is a quick way to get a rough idea

Comment: Sounds like an AOP problem.

Comment: Since Java 8 you can use the `org.openjdk.jmh` package explicitly designed for microbenchmarks.

Comment: Thanks @Glains for pointing out `org.openjdk.jmh` I'm looking at it, though that does not solve the original question